# How to simulate 1000 datasets, with each data set consisting of 100 random draws from the normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, dataset, simulation

I'm really new to R, and can't seem to figure out how to create a dataset consisting of 100 random draws. I can create 1 data set of 100 random draws using rnorm = (100,mean,sd) but I don't know how to create 1000 of these in a simple way...I would really appreciate it if someone could help me!

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=rnorm%20matrix for a great many examples.